# How to have the declaration and the definition of a function in different static libraries

Tags: c++, linker, inline

I would like to make this happen. To have a declaration of a function in one static library and it's definition in an other. Here is an example:

In LibA.a

```
// Foo.h
class Foo
{
public:
   void Bar() const;

};
```

In LibB.a

```
// FooPlatformSpecific.h
inline void Foo::Bar() const
{

}
```

And then in LibC.dylib

```
// Myfile.cpp
#include "Liba/Foo.h"
void useTheFunction()
{
   Foo foo;
   foo.Bar();
}
```

Some comments I need to make Bar inline so it doesn't generate duplicate symbol. Now my problem is that It doesn't link it gives me a undefined symbol.

A solution is to make the Bar definition not inline and in a cpp of LibB.a but that would hinder inline possibilities for the compiler.

Is there a way around this?

Comment: don't quite understand 'make Bar inline so it doesn't generate duplicate symbol'.  Also you need to put the implementation in the same CU if you really want the function inline.

Answer (score 0):

This is not going to work, since the *declaration* resides in the header, while the *definition* is in the library. So they are already separated, if you declare in `.h` and implement in `.cpp`.